# what is the exact use of setDownloadListener function in android

Tags: android, download

anybody used setDownloadListener in the code? what is the exact use of that? and what we can do in onDownloadStart function? can we download a file to our own location in sdcard? if possible how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-setDownloadListener can be used to listen when an download action is performed. it is useful when programmer want to handle the download activity without download manager

Answer (score 0):

Download the application using the link of SnapTube with the help of BlueStacks Emulator.
After completing [downloading](https://snaptubeofficial.com/snaptube-for-pc/) open the app and click on the Install button to proceed with the further steps.
Within Nanoseconds, the application will be installed and will be part of your Operating System.

Unwind the application and utilize all its features to make your free time more pleasant and exciting.